# getting crypto.subtle.encrypt to work like CryptoJS.AES.encrypt

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

I wrote a system that is implemented using CryptoJS.

After writing my code, I discovered `crypto.subtle.encrypt` which is an AES implementation built into browsers.

I want to change my code away from using CryptoJs and onto using crypto.subtle.encrypt.

Data encoded the old way (CryptoJS) has to be compatible with the new way (crypto.subtle.encrypt).

How can I achieve this?

When I wrote my original code, it looked much like this:

```
function cryptojs_encrypt(message) {
    var key = "my password";
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key).toString());
}
```

Where the "key" passed in is just a string. From what I've been able to read from other stackoverflow questions, CryptoJS converts this string into a "key" and "iv". How exactly is this achieved? I tried looking through the CryptoJS source code but couldn't find what I was looking for.

The way subtle.crypt.encrypt works, is that you have to pass in the key and iv explicitly. Here is my code:

```
function subtle_encrypt(message) {
    var msg = new TextEncoder().encode(message);
    var pass = new TextEncoder().encode('my password');
    var alg = { name: 'AES-CBC', iv: pass };
    crypto.subtle.importKey('raw', pass, alg, false, ['encrypt']).then(function(key){
        crypto.subtle.encrypt(alg, key, msg).then(function(ctBuffer){
            var string = btoa(ctBuffer);
            console.log("result", string);
        });
    });
}
```

This works but returns a different result. I need to modify the arguments that go into `alg` which matches what CryptoJS uses when you pass in a string. How do I do this?

Comment: You would have to implement OpenSSL's `EVP_BytesToKey` function which also needs MD5. This is not something that you want to re-implement, because it is not really secure. Also, it looks like MD5 is not available in the WebCrypto API

Comment: Adding to what @ArtjomB. says, crypto-js converts your pass phrase input into key and IV in a way that is compatible with OpenSSL (see interoperability section here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/ ).  OpenSSL conversion of pass phrase is described here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase .  It is disappointing that crypto-js is interoperating with a less than desirable security algorithm from OpenSSL.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a small library to do just that.

Embed [WebCrypto.js](https://github.com/etienne-martin/WebCrypto.swift/blob/master/WebCrypto.js) (Minified) in your document.

Use it like this:

```
// Initialize the library
initWebCrypto();

// Encrypt your stuff
WebCrypto.encrypt({
    data: btoa("my message"),
    password: "my password",
    callback: function(response){
        if( !response.error ){
            console.log(response.result); // Compatible with CryptoJS
        }else{
            console.error(response.error);
        }
    }
});
```

See https://github.com/etienne-martin/WebCrypto.swift/blob/master/www/index.html for more examples.

Source code: https://github.com/etienne-martin/WebCrypto.swift/blob/master/source.js

Hope this helps!